# Why fullCalendar doesn't show event?

Tags: json, symfony, fullcalendar

I try to show some events from database in my fullCalendar but it doesn't work? My app is on Symfony 3. First I installed the ancarebeca/fullcalendar, I followed the installation step by step and my agenda is here! In my controller, I have a method to return a JSON array like this:

> [{"1":{"id":1,"title":"test","start":"2017-08-01
>   18:00:00","end":"2017-08-01
>   20:00:00","allDay":true,"editable":true,"startEditable":true,"durationEditable":true,"overlap":true,"url":"","backgroundColor":"","textColor":"","className":"","rendering":"","constraint":1,"source":"","color":""},"2":{"id":2,"title":"test2","start":"2017-08-02
>   15:00:00","end":"2017-08-02
>   16:00:00","allDay":true,"editable":true,"startEditable":true,"durationEditable":true,"overlap":true,"url":"","backgroundColor":"","textColor":"","className":"","rendering":"","constraint":1,"source":"","color":""}}]

If you want look my method:

```
public function loadAction()
    {
        //dump($calendarService);die();
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $evenements = $em->getRepository('MALrmBundle:CalendarEvent')->findAll();

        $calendarService = $this->get('ma_lrm_bundle.service.listener');

        $events = array();

        foreach ($evenements as $key => $evenement)
        {

            $events[$evenement->getId()]=$calendarService->loadData($evenement);


        }

        $response = new JsonResponse($events);
        return $response->setData(array($events));

    }
```

At the end, in my js file, i just call the url, like this:

events: 'http://localhost/ligne_rh/web/app_dev.php/admin/accueil/calendar',

...But i have no return in my calendar...

i also post my full Js file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev, next',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month, agendaWeek, agendaDay'
            },
            timezone: ('Europe/London'),
            businessHours: {
                start: '09:00',
                end: '17:30',
                dow: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
            },
            allDaySlot: false,
            defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
            lazyFetching: true,
            firstDay: 1,
            selectable: true,
            timeFormat: {
                agenda: 'h:mmt',
                '': 'h:mmt'
            },
            /*columnFormat: {
                month: 'ddd',
                week: 'ddd D/M',
                day: 'dddd'
            },*/
            editable: true,
            eventDurationEditable: true,
            events: 'http://localhost/ligne_rh/web/app_dev.php/admin/accueil/calendar',

        });
});
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON is structured differently than it expects.

```
[{"1":{"title":"test","start":"2017-08-01 18:00"}}]
```

should be like

```
[{"title":"Title","test":"2017-08-01 18:00"}]
```

To fix, try changing

```
$events[$evenement->getId()]=$calendarService->loadData($evenement);
```

to

```
$events[]=$calendarService->loadData($evenement);
```

As an aside, I'm not familiar with Symphony but the return may be as easy as **return $response;**
since you already use **$events** in the **$response = new JsonResponse($events);**

or just **return new JsonResponse($events);**

Comment: Thank you for all!! your the best!! i fix the problem!!! now, i will try to render events by hours in the agendaWeek view.